# How to Rebase by date?

Tags: git, branch, commit, rebase, history

So I want to bring commits of another branch till specific date only and I want them to appear on my branch as if they were my branch's commit. So when I push my branch to github those commits should appear on top.

For ex: I want to bring 'main' branches commits to my 'dev' branch till let's say 2021.10.12 and when I push my branch to GitHub the commits must appear till 2021.10.12.

How is it possible?

So I tried `checkout main@{'date'}` but it is creating new pointing address, asking if I would like to publish it as new branch. But that is not what I want

Answer (score 1):

One way is :

```
# spot the commit on 'main' which you want to get,
# create a 'wip' branch on that commit:
git switch -c wip <commit>

# rebase that branch on top of your dev branch:
git rebase dev

# move your dev branch up to that point:
git checkout dev
git merge --ff-only wip

# you may now drop that wip branch:
git branch -d wip

# and push your dev branch:
git push origin dev
```

---

About the first command :

- `main@{'date'}` will not look for "the last commit before `'date'`", it will look into your local reflog (a history of what happened on your local repo), and get "the state `main` was in at `'date'` on your computer".
  So: suppose your main branch was 3 months old (you hadn't run `git pull` for a long time), and you ran `git pull` today, `main@{yesterday}` will translate to "the 3 month old `main`".

If you want to get "the state of upstream main at `'date'`", you can either:

- copy the commit hash from some graphical view of your history (for example: copy the hash from github's GUI when you inspect the list of commits on branch `main`)
- or use some of the many options of `git log` :

```
git log --until="<date>" -1 main

# or
git log --graph --oneline --until="<date>" main
   # and copy the hash from the first line

# or
git log --graph --oneline main
   # figure out up to what commit you want to include
   # and copy the sha of that commit
```

Comment: Thankyou for your detailed explanation. But what if I want to take multiple commits?

Comment: you're welcome. If you find this answer helpful, you can upvote it (and accept it, after a delay)

Comment: @Ben_96: `git rebase` will replay multiple commits. Is that what you were looking for ?

Comment: Yes, that was what i wanted. Thankyou one more time